# Automatically generated WAF solution fails to load

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, waf, cryengine

Cryengine as an SDK has recently switched from providing pre-made solutions to forcing developers to use a WAF based build system to automatically generate a visual studio solution.  Right now, there's very little communication coming from Crytek about problems everyone is having with the new build system so I was hoping someone here might be able to help.

I'm getting Cry-WAF (Crytek's WAF based build system) to generate a solution, but when I open it it provides an error (quoted below) and in the solution explorer appends (load failed) to each project in the solution.  I first had an issue generating the solutions with Cry-WAF's msvs.py script saying it couldn't gather properties for platforms/configurations, but that eventually stopped and allowed the solution to be generated with the quoted problem.

A generic google search on the root cause suggested I try enabling IIS, but that has done nothing to fix the problems.  Editing the .vcxproj files shows that they're correctly listing the paths to all files associated with that project.  The only thing missing in the solution seems to just be the information that would tell what compiler to use, target names, target paths, etc.  With what little I know about WAF as a build system, I'd assume that the python code Crytek is using to gather that information is just utterly failing.

Does anyone have a suggestion on what could possibly be done?

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\CRYENGINE\CRYENGINE_pc_eaascode\Solutions.depproj\CryAction.vcxproj : error  : The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.
>
> 1) Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: index
>
> Resulting in: An exception occurred while trying to get the value of property 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationMef.VCConfigurationShim'.
>
> Resulting in: Cannot get export 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationMef.VCConfigurationShim (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationShim")' from part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationMef'.
>   Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationMef.VCConfigurationShim (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationShim") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationMef
>
> Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator.VCConfiguration (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationShim")' on part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator'.
>   Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator.VCConfiguration (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationShim") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator
>
> Resulting in: Cannot get export 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator")' from part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator'.
>   Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator
>
> Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationMef.EventsTranslator (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator")' on part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationMef'.
>   Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationMef.EventsTranslator (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCLegacyEventsTranslator") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationMef
>
> Resulting in: Cannot get export 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationMef.VCConfigurationShim (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ConfiguredProject.HostObject")' from part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationMef'.
>   Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationMef.VCConfigurationShim (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ConfiguredProject.HostObject") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCConfigurationMef

Answer (score 1):

At the moment only Visual Studio 2012 is supported, so issues with Visual Studio 2013 are to be expected.

There is a thread on their forums dedicated to helping with WAF problems, which includes getting it up and running with Visual Studio 2013: http://www.cryengine.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=314&t=130850

The WAF documentation is here: http://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC4/Getting+Started+with+WAF

You will find help much more quickly on the CRYENGINE forums - few users habitually check Stack Overflow for these types of questions.